# How should I check if SSL session resumption is working or not?

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I'm using nginx, and want to implement SSL session resumption. How should we I test if it is working?

I have enabled these settings:

```
ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure of a way to test locally, but if your site is public, ssllabs provide a nice testing tool:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/index.html

Answer (score 27):

You can use openssl to test locally :

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -reconnect -no_ticket -servername example.com
```

`-servername` is required for SNI, and may be ignored otherwise

Or :

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -no_ticket -sess_out /tmp/ssl_s -servername example.com
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -no_ticket -sess_in /tmp/ssl_s -servername example.com
```

(The `-no_ticket` option is needed to disable [client-side TLS session tickets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5077) which also allow session resumption but is [a different setting](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_tickets) in `nginx`, and limit the test to the [server-side SSL session caching](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache) the OP's configuration controls.)

For the first command you'll get output like this :

```
drop connection and then reconnect
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Reused, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

For the last one, you'll get this in case of session resumption:

```
SSL handshake has read 142 bytes and written 583 bytes
---
Reused, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

or this in case of failure:

```
SSL handshake has read 5855 bytes and written 722 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

You can see the handshake is way bigger when it's new.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what the output means, and how to use it to determine if session resumption is working.

Comment: check for "Reused, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is <cipher>"

Comment: `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -reconnect -no_ticket -servername example.com | grep Reused`

-servername parameter must also be specified for SNI